# Swift UI Button doesnt compile

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to understand SwiftUI and got stuck on a problem where Xcode refuses to compile.

I have no clue why it allows to add 2 buttons, but complains when adding a third one.

Couldn't find an answer on SO.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginUI: View {

@State private var name = "dfdfdfdfdf"
@State private var logintitle = "LOGIN/LOGOUT"
@State private var xxx = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("login")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("loginusernametext")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)


            VStack {
                TextField(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Placeholder"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, text: $name)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)
        }
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("loginpassword")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)


            VStack {
                TextField("Password", text: $name)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)
        }
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("databasereference")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)


            VStack {
                TextField("Database", text: $name)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)
        }
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("carplate")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)


            VStack {
                TextField("Database", text: $name)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)
        }
        HStack {
            //GeometryReader { metrics in
            //  self.heigth = metrics.size.heigth
            Button(action: {
                self.doLogin()
            }) {
                Text(String("jaja"))

                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            //}
            //Image("aa14b")
            //    .background(Color.green)
            //     .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 80, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: self.heigth, alignment: .topLeading)

            Button(action: {
                self.doPause()
            }) {
                Text(String(self.xxx))

                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }

        }

        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.doLogin()
            }) {
                Text(String("odometerdelta"))

                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)

            }
        }
        HStack{
            Text(String("Loginexplain"))
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
}

func loginauthdelta(){

}
func doPause(){
    xxx += 1
}
func doLogin(){

}
struct LoginUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginUI()
    }
}
```

}

and here's the error

[image]

SO says: "
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", dont knwo how much I have to write until that error message goes away. Never seen this message before...

Comment: Code and errors should be added to the post as text, please.

Comment: Compiler often misplaces errors for SwiftUI code, would you provide your code for testing?

Comment: Edit your question and insert the code as text, apparently your button is correct, maybe the String(" ") inside the Text is wrong, can you show what is that?

Comment: Your sample code above compiles here. Have you tried cleaning the build folder and tried again? Or maybe the actual error is in another file?

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI has a hard limit on the number of elements in a view.

Try wrapping some of your top-level elements in a group...